# if "other" statement got chosen open textbox in infopath

Tags: infopath

I got a combo box control in a info path document that I just created, in the combo box I got few options and "other" option too. 
My goal is that if the user will chose the "other" option it will open a text box he could write in.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: Just set a rule to a new field which hides the field as long as the dropdown is not set to "other":

[image]

A user can enter data into the new field (textfield) if he selects other in the first field (combo/drodown).